# Raising an exception, Handling it. Only to raise it again; Python

Tags: python

I'm reading the Python Tutorial.

I came across a part that says:

'''
If you need to determine whether an exception was raised but don’t intend to handle it, a simpler form of the raise statement allows you to re-raise the exception:
'''

```
try:
    raise NameError('HiThere')
except NameError:
    print('An exception flew by!')
    raise
```

I don't understand why would one raise an exception, handle it and then re-raise it??

If the programmer doesn't want to handle the exception they shouldn't use a try..except statement in the first place??

Answer (score 4):

It helps if you don't think of exceptions as "mistakes" that have to be caught/corrected, and instead think of them as a way of communicating information.

Sometimes when you catch an exception it's expected, or you can find a way around it.  Other times, the exception means you can't do the thing you were trying to do, and so you want to raise an exception to your own caller to let them know why it's not going to work out.

When you're in that situation, sometimes you'll catch the lower-level exception that thwarted your plans, and then raise your own exception (maybe with a more specific type) to communicate your own failure to the caller.  Sometimes it might work just as well to simply raise the same exception back to the caller.  In the situation where you just want the lower level exception to go all the way up to the caller, you **might** opt to just not catch it, but what if you want to log a message or clean up some piece of internal state before you go down in flames?  That's where the `except`/`raise` pattern is useful.

```
begin_complicated_process()
try:
    do_risky_thing()
except ShenanigansError:
    log("Did someone say shenanigans?!")
    unwind_complicated_process()
    raise
complete_complicated_process()
```

Comment: Nope!  A `finally` is executed regardless of whether the exception is raised; you can't replace an `except` with a `finally` or vice versa and get the same behavior.  A more appropriate use of `finally` would be if you need to do some piece of finalization (like closing a file, say, or stopping a timer) regardless of success or failure.

Comment: A real-world example I can think of where I've used both is in a decorator function that does monitoring of other functions.  In a `try` block I start a timer and then execute the wrapped function I'm monitoring is executed under a `try`.  Under an `except` I log the failure and then `raise` (because I don't want to interfere with the operation of the function, just monitor it).  Under an `else` I log success.  Under the `finally` I stop the timer and report its value (since I want to do that either way).